# Get object from view to display in text! plugin of backbone project

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I am trying to display customer's sale history in a tab. 
When customer first click in to History tab, the data is displayed from Local Storage of the browser, other wise if the customer search for any specific information, data will gotten from web service(REST) in the form of JSON data.

**CustomerView.js**

```
define(["jquery" ,
       "underscore" ,
       "backbone",
       "text!templates/Customer/profile.html",
       "text!templates/Quotation/sale.html",
       "Quotation"
],function($,_,Backbone,CustomerProfile,SaleHistory,Quotation){
    var saleHistory = new Quotation();
    var CustomerView = Backbone.View.extend({
       initialize: function() {
       },
       el : "#container",
       events : {
          'click #searchSaleHistoryButton' : 'searchSaleHistory'
       },
       'searchSaleHistory' : function(){
           var saleHistoryObj = saleHistory.getSaleHistoryByID('877-04');
       },
       render: function(){
           var customerProfile = _.template(CustomerProfile);
           $(this.el).html(customerProfile);
       }   
   });
   return CustomerView;
});
```

I want to get `saleHistoryObj` to display in `sale.html` template instead of `history` object get from Local Storage, whenever user click on `searchSaleHistoryButton`.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

**sale.html**

```
<%
   var history  = localStorage.getItem("SaleHistory");
   var historyLength = history.HistoryData.length;
   if(historyLength > 0){
%>
    <table class="defaultHisTbl">
            <% for(var i = 0; i < historyLength; i++){ %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= history.HistoryData[i].QuotationNumber%></td>
                <td><%= history.HistoryData[i].InvoiceNumber%></td>
                <td><%= history.HistoryData[i].QuotationDate%></td>
            </tr>
            <% } %>
    </table>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Recommend you to use Backbone.Model and Backbone.Collection?

Lets expect Model and Collection like this:

```
var profileModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        QuotationNumber: 0,
        InvoiceNumber: 0,
        QuotationDate: '00-00-00' 
    } 
});

var profileCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: profileModel
});
```

Then lets update the views:

```
var profileItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tag: 'tr',
    template: _.template(CustomerProfile),
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html( this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    }
});

var profileCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'table',
    render: function(){
        this.collection.each(function(profile){
            var itemView = new PersonView({ model: profile });
            this.$el.append(itemView.render().el); 
        }, this);
    }
});
```

Then lets update the template. Expect CustomerProfile as

```
<td><%= QuotationNumber %></td>
<td><%= InvoiceNumber %></td>
<td><%= QuotationDate %></td>
```

Highly recommend you to checkout [this post](http://www.codebeerstartups.com/2012/12/9-collection-views-in-backbone-js-learning-backbone-js) its very useful in case of rendering collections in table view.

So to reach you goal you should listen the click on profileCollectionView and set data to collection from localStorage or from server json. You may need to override **render()** method in case of async json. You can use events 'fetch' and 'reset' to manage it:

```
var profileCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'table',

    initialize: function(){
        this.collection = new profileCollection();
        this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);
        this.collection.fetch({reset: true});
    },

    events : {
       'click .btn' : 'resetCollection'
    },

    resetCollection : function(){
       var saleHistoryObj = saleHistory.getSaleHistoryByID('877-04');
       this.collection.reset(saleHistoryObj);
    },

    render: function(){
        this.collection.each(function(profile){
            var itemView = new PersonView({ model: profile });
            this.$el.append(itemView.render().el); 
        }, this);
    }
});

// lets create a view 

var view  = new profileCollectionView({ el : '.some_node' });
```

Comment: To be frank, I'd never used model and collection before, I'm just a newbie to backbone.js. And have been spending these 2 days to checkout and learned your link shared to me, I start to understand about it step by step. I create the code in your answer, then, I don't know where should I render/call `profileCollectionView` in my main View (`CustomerView.js`)

Comment: you should call render on profileCollectionView instance. In practice very often {el : '.selector'} passing into instance to hook it up with DOM. You can also use it. var profColView = new profileCollectionView({el : '.existing_node', collection: ..}) . Also you can ask collection to fetch on init if you dont fetched it before  -  initialize: function(){ ... collection.fetch({reset: true})}

Comment: hmmm it is too mainstream to describe, should I modify my code block in my question or create a new question to show the code :/

Comment: I got an error `Uncaught Error: A "url" property or function must be specified`

Comment: Yeap, its expexted, add url: 'where.get.collection.data.json in profileCollection

Comment: Ok, the error is fixed. But the button did not work, or maybe we missed rendering `profileCollectionView` ?

Comment: profileCollectionView is rendered. But the button action still didn't fire.

Comment: is button inside profileCollectionView template and has class .btn ?

Comment: looks like we need fiddle.

Comment: One more thing, It has an error `TypeError: this.model is undefined` when I initialized `profileCollection` in `profileCollectionView ` (`this.collection = new profileCollection();`)

Comment: looks like you have to checkout that JSON format you receive from saleHistory.getSaleHistoryByID('877-04'); - looks like the problem there. Wnen you try to render first PersonView it receive something strange instead model

Comment: Nope dear! I just put a line `this.collection = new profileCollection();` in `profileCollectionView` then the error is occur.