# Render backbone template using JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I have a JSON object that i would like to render using the backbone template.
My JSON looks something like this:

[image: JSON object]

Also i have this underscore that im using for the rendering.
Underscore:

```
<div id="sub-accounts">
    <table>
    <tbody>
    <th>Name</th>

    <% _.each(accountList, function(account) { %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= account.get('description') %></td>
                                    <td><%= account.get('id') %></td>
                                     <td><%= account.get('name') %></td>
            </tr>
        <% }) %>
    </tbody>
       </table>

    </div>
```

EDIT::::
Below is how my render function looks like: In my view list, im fetching the data, as accountList.fetch() and on success, im displaying the data from json to a template. My `._template(tmpl)` has a template im passing it in here: `function($, _, Backbone, tmpl){ 
});` I still dont get anything to display when i pass this data. what im i doing wrong? Any thoughts???

```
render: function(accountId){

            this.$el = $('#sub-account-list');
            var self = this;
            var accountList = new SubAccountCollection({accountId:accountId });
            accountList.fetch({
                success: function(accnlist){
                    var data = accnlist.toJSON();
                    console.log('inside the success func' + data[0].data.items[0].name)
                    self.$el .html(_.template(tmpl), {accnlist:data})   
                },
            });                 
        }
```

How can i pass the json object to render data using the template? Any ideas??

Comment: create model, collection, modelView and collectionView. Use your template in modelView. Pass you json to collection instance as data or fetch this data from backend. render() your collectionView. checkout this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24113219/get-object-from-view-to-display-in-text-plugin-of-backbone-project/24114153#24114153

Comment: @Evgeniy: 
Thanks for the link, above in the EDIT code is what i tried, with minimum luck of getting my data to display..what im doing wrong??Thanks in advance..